# Button Tag Not Working

Tags: html

I want to redirect `<button>` tag to specific page/url. I am not sure what's wrong with my code.

```
<button onclick="location.href='http://google.com';" value="Go to Google">Take Me To Google</button>
```

This is the code I'm using. It's not working as we do with input & a tag

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jwocujn1

Comment: Try with `https` in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *cannot* navigate to a different URL which restricts the other domains from accessing them due to as a result of protection.

> This issue is commonly knows as **Cross-Origin Resource Sharing** (C.O.R.S.). You can read about it in depth [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Out of many, **Google**  is one.

You can try by replacing the URL from google to other for example bing: ->

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='https://www.bing.com';" value="Bing">Bing</button>
```

And it will work, because, bing allows other URLs to access it without any C.O.R.S.

As far as your `code` is concerned, I find nothing wrong with your code.

Hope this answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com';" value="Google">
  Google
</button>
```

Comment: Yes, just perfect :) Thanks Mate